# Can't initialize AVPlayer with iPod music

Tags: iphone, ios, avplayer, mpmediaitem

I am trying to initialize an AVPlayer with the contents of a song from the device iPod library. I have the following code in a viewDidLoad of my root controller (extracted it into a test app to isolate it).

```
MPMediaQuery* query = [MPMediaQuery songsQuery];

MPMediaItem* firstItem = [query.items objectAtIndex:0];
NSURL* url = [firstItem valueForKey:MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL];
AVPlayerItem* playerItem = [[AVPlayerItem alloc] initWithURL:url];

self.player = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithPlayerItem:playerItem];
[self.player play];
```

The code always throws the following exception at the line where I call valueForKey on firstItem in order to obtain the asset URL.:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key assetURL.'
>   *** First throw call stack:

The code seems pretty straight forward to me, not sure what I might be missing here, any help would be fantastic. This is iOS 5.1 on an iPhone 4S. Tried with both iTunes Match enabled and with a device that only has local music, same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [valueForProperty:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMediaEntity_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/MPMediaEntity/valueForProperty%3a) method instead.

Comment: Thanks, that did it. A very subtle oversight on my part.